# How to get property value from an array of objects to compare values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I want to get the name property value from this array and filter it's value to a search input data to sort items
how can I do that?

```
 items: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Brown Brim',
                imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/ZYW3VTp/brown-brim.png',
                price: 25
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Blue Beanie',
                imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/ypkgK0X/blue-beanie.png',
                price: 18
            }
```

i tried using find() method but it return every object that has a name property

```
items.find(item => item.name).name.icludes(searchData)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: *"...but it return every object that has a name property..."* Only if `searchData` is `""`.  Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const newData = items.filter(item => item.name === searchData);
```

Use `newData` for your operation.

Comment: it gives an array of objects that matches the searchData but i want all the name values not their objects

Comment: try now, I have update the answer

Answer (score 0):

### **UPDATED ANSWER**

You said,

> I want to get the name property value from this array and filter it's value to a search input data to sort items how can I do that?

Reply me if this isn't what you want,

1 => Get an array with only name fields in it.

```
items.map(item => item.name);
`[ 'Brown Brim', 'Blue Beanie' ]`
```

2 => Then filter the new array according to `searchData`.

```
.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().includes(searchData.toLowercase()));
```

3 => And sort the filtered array.

```
.sort()
```

4 => finally all together.

> Make sure to assign a variable as `newArray` because the `items` array will stay exact the same and our function will return the filtered & sorted array to variable we assign.

```
  const newArray = items.map(item => item.name)
      .filter(item => item.toLowerCase().includes(searchData.toLowerCase()))
      .sort();
```

---

### OLD ANSWER

I've modified [@sushildlh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5305430/sushildlh) answer to a more safer version

```
const filteredData = items.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchData.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: it gives me an array of objects that matches the condition but i want to compare searchData and name of every item

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. so what you want is to sort the array of object with the name field to alphabetical order. please add more context.

Comment: Think I finally understood what you wanted. Check the Updated answer above. Please add more context next time.